# Concatenating columns using CTE in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, common-table-expression

I have a table like

`TABLEX` -

```
+------+------------+
| NAME | TABLE_NAME |
+------+------------+
| X1   | X001       |
| X2   | X002       |
+------+------------+
```

This table contains a name column which is nothing but description and a table_name column which is actually a table already present in the database.

`X001` Table has columns like `X1_A, X1_B` 
`X002` Table has columns like `X2_A, X2_B`

Now I want to concatenate all columns in the actual table present in the `TABLE_NAME` column in a comma separated string and display that as a column.

```
+------+------------+------------+
| NAME | TABLE_NAME |  COLUMNS   |
+------+------------+------------+
| X1   | X001       | X1_A, X1_B |
| X2   | X002       | X2_A, X2_B |
+------+------------+------------+
```

Now can this be achieved using CTE. I've already successfully created the query using `STUFF` with `XML PATH`, but I'm having performance issues because there are like 200 odd rows in the table that I've show above and each subsequent tables linked have like 100 columns each.

**EDIT -**

```
SELECT 
P.NAME,
P.TABLE_NAME,
[COLUMNS]=(SELECT STUFF((SELECT ',' + NAME FROM sys.syscolumns WHERE ID = OBJECT_ID(P.TABLE_NAME) ORDER BY colorder FOR XML PATH('') ), 1, 1,''))
FROM TABLEX P
```

Where `TABLEX` is the table posted above.

Comment: Can you post your existing code?  Why do you need to concatenate 100 columns of data?

Comment: @bluefeet I think they just want a comma delimited list of column names.

Comment: Given that they just want column names, why do the number of rows in the table matter?  I'm trying to build a solution using INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS and XML PATH.

Comment: @wagregg The table containing the list of table names has 200 rows. I would steer clear of `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` and use `sys.columns` for better performance.

Comment: @MartinSmith Possibly true, that is why I asked to see their actual code so it would be clear on what they are concatenating.

Comment: @MartinSmith I just saw that `sys.syscolumns` out performs `sys.columns` and `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` by a margin of atleast 15 secs.

Comment: The query on `sys.columns` ought to be just as fast as long as you are looking up by a sargable expression on `object_id`

Comment: @MartinSmith ***"I think they just want a comma delimited list of column names."*** You're absolutely right.

Comment: Some helpful info here: [The case against INFORMATION_SCHEMA views](https://sqlblog.org/2011/11/03/the-case-against-information_schema-views).

Comment: With 200 tables and 100 columns in each table the `for xml` query takes 100 ms on my computer and it takes almost 1 second in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b07bb/1). What could be the reason for this to execute so much slower for you?  How many rows do you have in `sys.syscolumns`?

Comment: @MikaelEriksson Almost 60-70 columns per table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one -

**DDL:**

```
IF OBJECT_ID (N'dbo.TABLEX') IS NOT NULL
   DROP TABLE TABLEX

IF OBJECT_ID (N'dbo.X001') IS NOT NULL
   DROP TABLE X001

IF OBJECT_ID (N'dbo.X002') IS NOT NULL
   DROP TABLE X002

CREATE TABLE dbo.TABLEX (NAME VARCHAR(50), TABLE_NAME VARCHAR(50))
INSERT INTO dbo.TABLEX (NAME, TABLE_NAME)
VALUES ('X1', 'X001'), ('X2', 'X002')

CREATE TABLE dbo.X001 (X1_A VARCHAR(50), X1_B VARCHAR(50))
CREATE TABLE dbo.X002 (X2_A VARCHAR(50), X2_B VARCHAR(50))
```

**Query:**

```
;WITH cte AS
(
     SELECT 
            NAME
          , TABLE_NAME
          , [COLUMN] = CAST('' AS VARCHAR(1024))
          , POS = 1
     FROM TABLEX t

     UNION ALL

     SELECT 
            t.NAME
          , t.TABLE_NAME
          , CAST([COLUMN] + ', ' + c.name AS VARCHAR(1024))
          , POS + 1
     FROM cte t
     JOIN sys.columns c ON 
                 OBJECT_ID('dbo.' + t.TABLE_NAME) = c.[object_id] 
               AND 
                 t.POS = c.column_id
)
SELECT 
       NAME
     , TABLE_NAME
     , [COLUMNS] = STUFF([COLUMN], 1, 2, '')
FROM (
     SELECT *, rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY NAME ORDER BY POS DESC)
     FROM cte
) t
WHERE t.rn = 1
```

**Results:**

```
NAME   TABLE_NAME    COLUMNS
------ ------------- -------------
X1     X001          X1_A, X1_B
X2     X002          X2_A, X2_B
```

**Query cost:**

[image: Query Cost]

**Statistic:**

```
    Query Presenter  Scans  Logical Reads
-------------------  -----  -------------
                XML      5              9
                CTE      3             48
```

Comment: Somehow on my server the `CTE` is performing better but is taking more time. I don't know why. Can you shed some light on that. Also I had to include `OPTION(MAXRECURSION 150)` to include all columns.

Comment: This might have different results order as there is no `order by colorder` included here. That is why it has better performance too, drop the `order by colorder` in the original query and you will have the same performance.

Comment: @SohamDasgupta The cost in the query plan is an estimate done before the query is actually executed. What performance you have for the query needs to be measured and if you have longer execution time on the CTE version I would claim that CTE is not as fast as the XML version.

Comment: @Justicator I see. But its not possible to include the `Order By colorder` in the answered query now is it?

Comment: @MikaelEriksson But shouldn't it be faster?

Comment: @SohamDasgupta I don't think the CTE version is faster. Perhaps it could be faster in some circumstances but I have not seen that.